# CSS nth-child property does not work correctly when dynamically adding items

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some divs defined in my page

```
<div class="alternating">random text</div>
<div class="alternating">random text</div>
<div class="alternating">random text</div>
<div class="alternating">random text</div>
<div class="alternating">random text</div>
```

I have added a css property

```
.alternating:nth-child(even){
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

On the loading the page everything seems fine and the even rows are colored.
But when I add a new div to the parents of this divs (using Knockout and jquery) the newly adding row does not show the right color.
That means if my last line was odd (no color) the newly added div also appears with no color.
Or if the last div was even (with color) the newly added div also appears with color.

But after that it works out normal again.
My problem is only on the addition of the 1st div.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to dynamically add divs?

Comment: what browser are you using? does the same bug occur in all browsers?

Comment: Here's the first step if you need it: http://jsfiddle.net/mXMDD/. This is your code and basic idea which seems to work fine. Tell us how it's not (could be a browser issue?).

Comment: if you add div after loading the page you need to reload the css file after adding the div in this case,

Comment: It works fine so far as I can tell. http://jsfiddle.net/6tPwU/ ... perhaps you can reset the numbering with something like: `$('.alertnating').removeClass('alternating').addClass('alternating');`

Comment: very nyc solution @ Dom Day

Comment: In your code that handles adding the dynamic elements, add some logic that check if it's a even sibling and add a class if it's even. Then style the class. Make a fiddle with your html, js and css for us to clearly show you a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/uZ5wn/) in which I start with divs in the DOM, then add them by a click.

Relevant: JS

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.holder').append("<div class='inside'>dynamic div</div>");
});
```

Relevant CSS

```
.holder {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.inside {
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.inside:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer it helped me fixed some other bugs. But my main problem really was that i had random hidden rows appearing.